# Getting Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given when trying to mock redis using node

Tags: node.js, jestjs, node-redis

When attempting to run below simple test I get this error

● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given

  1 | import redis from 'redis';
  2 | import redis_mock from 'redis-mock';
> 3 | jest.spyOn(redis, 'createClient').mockImplementation(redis_mock.createClient);
    |      ^

import redis from 'redis';
import redis_mock from 'redis-mock';
jest.spyOn(redis, 'createClient').mockImplementation(redis_mock.createClient);

describe('something', () => {
    it('should pass', () => expect(true).toBeTruthy())
});
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure Redis is actually imported? Maybe you need `import * as redis`? According to your error message `redis` has an undefined value

Comment: Thanks, this seem to be the issue here